# Device Dicovery file of ONVIF library in android studio

Tags: java, android, network-programming, ip-camera, onvif

I find out a library of `JavaWsDiscovery-0.2.jar`. It is find out the ONVIF camera on same network, when I simply run the jar file in android studio, it runs successfully.

But when I want to use it in our project, it does not run just because of Private method.

In this library two methods are private those are not accessible to another class.

When i editing in jar file. so, it shows the compilation Error.

So, I need help in this regard, thank you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
ListView values;
List<String> value;
String[] args;
public static int WS_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT = 4000;
public static int WS_DISCOVERY_PORT = 3702;
public static String WS_DISCOVERY_ADDRESS_IPv4 = "239.255.255.250";
public static String WS_DISCOVERY_ADDRESS_IPv6 = "[FF02::C]";
public static String WS_DISCOVERY_PROBE_MESSAGE = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing\" xmlns:tns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery\"><soap:Header><wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:c032cfdd-c3ca-49dc-820e-ee6696ad63e2</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To></soap:Header><soap:Body><tns:Probe/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
private static final Random random = new SecureRandom();
String filepath = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.onvif.camera/com.onvif.javaWsDiscovery-0.2.jar";

static DeviceDiscovery deviceDiscovery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    deviceDiscovery = new DeviceDiscovery();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    values = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.values);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                main(args);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Iterator i$ = discoverWsDevicesAsUrls().iterator();
    while(i$.hasNext()) {
        URL url = (URL)i$.next();
        System.out.println("Device discovered: " + url.toString());
    }
}

public static Collection<URL> discoverWsDevicesAsUrls() {
    return discoverWsDevicesAsUrls("", "");
}

public static Collection<URL> discoverWsDevicesAsUrls(String regexpProtocol, String regexpPath) {
    TreeSet urls = new TreeSet(new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    });
    Iterator i$ = discoverWsDevices().iterator();

    while(i$.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)i$.next();

        try {
            URL e = new URL(key);
            boolean ok = true;
            if(regexpProtocol.length() > 0 && !e.getProtocol().matches(regexpProtocol)) {
                ok = false;
            }

            if(regexpPath.length() > 0 && !e.getPath().matches(regexpPath)) {
                ok = false;
            }

            if(ok) {
                urls.add(e);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException var7) {
            var7.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return urls;
}

public static Collection<String> discoverWsDevices() {
    final ConcurrentSkipListSet addresses = new ConcurrentSkipListSet();
    final CountDownLatch serverStarted = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch serverFinished = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ArrayList addressList = new ArrayList();

    try {
        Enumeration executorService = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        if(executorService != null) {
            label45:
            while(true) {
                NetworkInterface ignored;
                do {
                    if(!executorService.hasMoreElements()) {
                        break label45;
                    }

                    ignored = (NetworkInterface)executorService.nextElement();
                } while(ignored.isLoopback());

                List address = ignored.getInterfaceAddresses();
                Iterator runnable = address.iterator();

                while(runnable.hasNext()) {
                    InterfaceAddress address1 = (InterfaceAddress)runnable.next();
                    addressList.add(address1.getAddress());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException var10) {
        var10.printStackTrace();
    }

    ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Iterator ignored1 = addressList.iterator();

    while(ignored1.hasNext()) {
        final InetAddress address2 = (InetAddress)ignored1.next();
        Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String e = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    String probe = WS_DISCOVERY_PROBE_MESSAGE.replaceAll("<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:.*</wsa:MessageID>", "<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:" + e + "</wsa:MessageID>");
                    int port = random.nextInt(20000) + '鱀';
                    final DatagramSocket server = new DatagramSocket(port, address2);
                    (new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                DatagramPacket e = new DatagramPacket(new byte[4096], 4096);
                                server.setSoTimeout(WS_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT);
                                long timerStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                while(System.currentTimeMillis() - timerStarted < (long)WS_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT) {
                                    serverStarted.countDown();
                                    server.receive(e);
                                    Collection collection = deviceDiscovery.parseSoapResponseForUrls(Arrays.copyOf(e.getData(), e.getLength()));
                                    Iterator i$ = collection.iterator();

                                    while(i$.hasNext()) {
                                        String key = (String)i$.next();
                                        addresses.add(key);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (SocketTimeoutException var11) {
                                ;
                            } catch (Exception var12) {
                                var12.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                serverFinished.countDown();
                                server.close();
                            }

                        }
                    }).start();

                    try {
                        serverStarted.await(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException var7) {
                        var7.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(address2 instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        server.send(new DatagramPacket(probe.getBytes(), probe.length(), InetAddress.getByName(WS_DISCOVERY_ADDRESS_IPv4), WS_DISCOVERY_PORT));
                    } else {
                        server.send(new DatagramPacket(probe.getBytes(), probe.length(), InetAddress.getByName(WS_DISCOVERY_ADDRESS_IPv6), WS_DISCOVERY_PORT));
                    }
                } catch (Exception var8) {
                    var8.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    serverFinished.await((long)WS_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException var6) {
                    var6.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        executorService1.submit(runnable1);
    }

    try {
        executorService1.shutdown();
        executorService1.awaitTermination((long)(WS_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT + 2000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException var9) {
        ;
    }

    return addresses;
}
}
```

**DeviceDiscovery.class**

```
private static Collection<Node> getNodeMatching(Node body, String regexp) {
    ArrayList nodes = new ArrayList();
    if(body.getNodeName().matches(regexp)) {
        nodes.add(body);
    }

    if(body.getChildNodes().getLength() == 0) {
        return nodes;
    } else {
        NodeList returnList = body.getChildNodes();

        for(int k = 0; k < returnList.getLength(); ++k) {
            Node node = returnList.item(k);
            nodes.addAll(getNodeMatching(node, regexp));
        }

        return nodes;
    }
}

private static Collection<String> parseSoapResponseForUrls(byte[] data) throws SOAPException, IOException {
    ArrayList urls = new ArrayList();
    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance(WS_DISCOVERY_SOAP_VERSION);
    MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("Content-type", WS_DISCOVERY_CONTENT_TYPE);
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(headers, new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
    Iterator i$ = getNodeMatching(body, ".*:XAddrs").iterator();

    while(i$.hasNext()) {
        Node node = (Node)i$.next();
        if(node.getTextContent().length() > 0) {
            urls.addAll(Arrays.asList(node.getTextContent().split(" ")));
        }
    }

    return urls;
}
```

I want to use both method of `DeviceDiscovery.class`. But it's not accessible because it's a private method.

I am not able to editing in `DeviceDiscovery.class` because it's a part of jar file and it's only readable form.

This is the error I have:

```
(216, 80) error: parseSoapResponseForUrls(byte[]) has private access in DeviceDiscovery
```

Comment: Can you add to the question the error trace?

Comment: Kindly, check the editing part of 'MainActivity' and 'DeviceDiscovery' java file and thank you for editing @Kalamarico

Comment: Sure, the question have a lot of quality, sure you will have answers soon